# Cross Domain File Upload (From Extension)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cross-browser, crossrider

I am trying to create an extensions with Crossrider that also needs to upload a file.

My issues is that the app code is running on one domain site1.com but the file needs to be uploaded to site2.com.

Do you have any suggestion on if and how is this possible ?

Comment: can you open an iframe from site2.com and upload the file in the iframe?